# Functional tests in symfony3, access to container after submitting a form

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit

I'm writing functional tests for my Symfony3 application. I have a test which looks like this:

```
public function testList()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->getCookieJar()->set($this->cookie);

    $this->sender->method('isSuccessfull')->will($this->returnValue(true));

    $container = $client->getContainer();
    $container->set('app.service1', $this->object1);
    $container->set('app.service2', $this->object2);

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/list/1');
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Save')->form();
    $client->submit($form);

}
```

Everything is good until submitting form. Kernel losing the setted container services while submitting a form. How can I these services into container also after submitting a form? Maybe there is other option to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [source code for `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client::doRequest()` class](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php#L77) you can see that it terminates the kernel which is then started again later and that's why you loose all service you created manually.

I guess you have an app which you're testing so you could add the services to its `services.yml`. Another way could be extending the `Client` class with your own and overriding `getContainer()` method to always add these extra services (then you'd have to update the service definition for `test.client` in a compile pass with your customized class).

Comment: Thank you for response. My services aren't "real" services. They are mock of real services. Do you have an idea how to pass the mock of the service in the services_test.yml or add these mocks in the extended Client class?

Comment: Adding them into `test_service.yml` that imports the regular `service.yml` is even easier that extending `Client` so I'd go with just `yml`s unless you need also some extra functionality.

Comment: Ok I know that :) But how to pass mocks as the argument of service? In my code above mocks are $this->object1 and $this->object2.

Comment: I don't know what's `object1` nor `object2`. Just define them as services I guess.

Comment: It's not so simple, because object1 and object2 are phpunit mocks. Example of defined object:      $this->object1 = $this->getMockBuilder('AppBundle\Object\Object1')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(['method1', 'method2'])
            ->getMock()

Comment: @MateuszRavage Then extend the `Client` class with your own